# Display files contain inside a particular directory by using C++ in LINUX

Tags: c++, linux

I'm working on assignment for my university. I have a question on how to display all the files contain inside a particular directory. My working environment is on LINUX UBUNTU 14.04 G++ Compiler.

Let's take an example, I want to display/output all the files inside this DIRECTORY

```
/home/user/Desktop/TEST/FileSystem

File contains inside FOLDER FileSystem
-test.txt
-abc.txt
-item.txt
-records.txt
```

I'm not sure whether it can be done by using:

-Using Execute System Command, by calling standard library header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("pwd");  // Directory: /home/user/Desktop/TEST/FileSystem
    system("ls");   // Display every files contain in the FileSystem Folder 
}
```

OUTPUT that I expected:

```
/FileSystem Folder contains:

    -test.txt
    -abc.txt
    -item.txt
    -records.txt
```

How can I code my source code so that I'm able to achieving this OUTPUT/Display that I expected. I have go through some internet sources by googling it. But I find out difficulty on understand it. That's why I have made a decision to post my question on here.

Thank You in advance to you guys for helping me to solve my coding problem.

Comment: Read about [the Boost Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Boost Filesystem or Qt with its QDir class.

When you lunch the system() command, you should somehow capture the output. Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: @blackibiza wow, this is another great solution. I'll try to implement it. Thank You :)

Comment: @J4X no problem. This might reduce the requirement of external libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first open directory for which you need to list files after that you need to read directory.

Add **#include**  for using apis.

```
#include <dirent.h>

/* open the directory "/home/" for reading. */ 
DIR* dir = opendir("/home/users");

entry = readdir(dir)); //files or directories in /home 

//Add logic to verify entry is file or directory
```

Refer this thread http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/107_6.htm

Comment: Thank You @Rahul for providing the snippets of the code and also the link. I've tried to implement on my program and it works perfectly as the expected output that I want.

Answer (score 0):

the function

```
system("ls")
```

is just firing the command but you are missing what the output of the command *ls* is.
You need to capture it.
In [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c) it's explained how to do it.